# What happens when the north most and south most poles of the magnets connected in "series" meet to form a donut shape?

Tags: electromagnetism

Imagine a series of magnets connected together to form a donut shape or loop, what will happen while and/or after connecting the North and South poles of the first and last magnets to complete the loop/donut?

Answer (score 1):

If you do this with an electromagnet, the field is referred to as a [toroid](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html). As with a  [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid), if the coil windings are dense enough, you can have a quite strong field within the torus but a negligible field outside of it.

You can make a toroid with permanent magnets, but most people don't, because in that case also the external field becomes small.  However, you can wrap an electromagnetic coil around a high-permeability "magnetic yoke" to mostly confine your magnetic field to the material of the yoke, except for a strong and relatively uniform field spanning any small gaps. Old physics textbooks have a chapter on "magnetic circuits" which describes designing magnetic field systems like this.  In the image below, there are two high-field gaps labeled $G$, with a "fringing field" $B_F$ near the gaps and a "leakage field" $B_L$ closer to the coil.

> [image]
> Source: [Chetvorno](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Electromagnet_with_gap.svg), Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons